# How to choose appropriate Scalar values when using InRange in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, colors, range, scalar, threshold

I am trying to detect the white shapes in an object and can successfully do it for 1 video.

```
// Create and display a new matrix for triangles
triangles = src.clone();
GaussianBlur(triangles, triangles, Size(5, 5), 0, 0);
inRange(triangles, Scalar(150,150,150), Scalar(255, 255, 255), triangles);
imshow("triangles", triangles);
```

This gives me the result

http://s8.postimg.org/o9xg284jp/triangles.png

However, if I use a different video - then the scalar value of 150 may not be appropriate (for example if it is a light environment... everything gets detected)

http://s8.postimg.org/m09brgvlx/bad_triangles.png

For this video I would need to change the minimum scalar to be around 190-200 for it to work properly. My question - is there a good way to determine the correct scalar value to use? I know it sounds simple to some, but ive got a headache because of it!

Answer (score 2):

http://colorizer.org/

If you check here you can see what your problem is. RGB = (255, 155, 155) is probably not a "white" but your inRange method is giving true output to that one.

Try to use HSL color space. Lightness > 90 is white for sure, no matter what H and S channel values are. Use [BGR2HLS conversion.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) Then use inRange with L channel between 90-100.

Actually, for color detection problems, mostly used color spaces are HSV and HSL, not RGB!

Answer (score 0):

There is  probably no way to automatically determine a threshold that works for all kind of videos. But to make it less dependent on the overall lightning of the video you could make it depend on the mean or median pixel value of the image.

Or if you know how big your object appears in the image, you could choose the threshold accordingly.

Another approach could be to normalize the brightness of the video.

But which approach is best strongly dependents on your exact situation and requirements.